# bind_result() not binding variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following code is producing the error: `Notice: Undefined variable: morrisons`.

I have absolutely no idea why this error is occuring, it seems to be a problem with the actual assigned variable in that it just doesn't get assigned.

```
$sql = "SELECT name
        FROM stds
        INNER JOIN `users`
        ON users.`id` = stds.`id`
        WHERE users.`username` = ?";

if ($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($morrisons);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}

echo $morrisons;
```

Comment: I think u have to check value $morrisons.$stmt->bind_result($morrisons);

Comment: check what bind_result returns! It must be true

Comment: @Passerby Thanks! That was the issue. I do find it a little odd how the fact that the query returned no results should mean it returns no variable. It would have been much nicer of PHP to set the $morrisons variable to 'null' so at least then I would have known it was a problem with the query. Feel free to submit as answer and I will select as best!

Comment: @jskidd3 Thanks and congrats, but I was just guessing, so I think that doesn't qualify an answer. Although you can post your finding as the answer and accept it (might need 48 hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $stmt->bind_result($morrisons);
```

This line only executes if this line

```
if ($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
```

produces a `true` result. Otherwise the whole block is skipped and `$morrisons` never gets declared. So this line

```
echo $morrisons;
```

will produce an error. So the root cause is that `$db->prepare` returns `false`, which means the query is wrong in some way or the database connection is gone. Check for errors in this case.